# How to redirect to a different page after a redux action using react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-form, redux-saga

I'm building a web app, and I want users to confirm their emails before they are able to sign in. I am using redux and have a redux action where I confirm the user. After I confirm the user, I want to reroute the user to the sign in page, with a two seconds timeout. I've included by redux action to confirm the user, as well as my Confirm component, and my App.js, so you can see the routing as well. For the routing, I have wrapped all my routes in a switch. I'd really appreciate any help, it would really mean a lot to me, as I am pretty stuck on this. Also, if you have any questions about my code, let me know. Thank you!

confirm action:

```
// Confirm User
export const confirm = (email, code) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: CONFIRM_STARTED
  });
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/auth/confirm?email=${email}&code=${code}`)

    dispatch({
      type: CONFIRM_SUCCESS
    });


  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }


    dispatch({
      type: CONFIRM_FAIL
    });
  }
}
```

Confirm component:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { confirm } from '../../actions/auth';



class Confirm extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    //console.log("test ()");
    let email = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search).get("email");
    let code = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search).get("code");
    this.props.confirm(email, code);
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
        <div>
          {this.props.confirmed}
          {this.props.confirming}
        </div>
        <div>
          We have confirmed your account, you may now login!
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  confirm: (email, code) => dispatch(confirm(email, code))
})

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  confirmed: state.auth.emailConfirmed,
  confirming: state.auth.emailConfirming
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Confirm);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Alert from './components/layout/Alert';
// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { loadUser } from './actions/auth';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';
import Profile from './components/profile/Profile';
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRoute';
import CreateChat from './components/chat-form/CreateChat';
import JoinChat from './components/chat-form/JoinChat';
import Chat from './components/profile/Chat';
//import PostForm from './components/profile/PostForm';
import AboutChat from './components/profile/AboutChat';
import Post from './components/profile/Post';
import CommentForm from './components/profile/CommentForm';
import Confirm from './components/profile/Confirm';

import './App.css';

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <section className="container">
            <Alert />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/create-chat' component={CreateChat} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/join-chat' component={JoinChat} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/chat/:id' component={Chat} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/comment-form/:chatId/:postId' component={CommentForm} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/chat-details/:id' component={AboutChat} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/post/:chatId/:postId' component={Post} />
              <Route exact path='/confirm' component={Confirm} />
            </Switch>
          </section>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example that might help. Click the `Confirm` button to imperatively `push` onto the `history` stack. Once you are "logged in", a timeout begins running and 3 seconds later you are declaratively "logged out" using the `Redirect` component and some conditional logic. You are subsequently returned to the Login page.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-shape-m3s82?file=/src/index.js:0-932)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Switch,
  useHistory,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

function Login() {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Login</p>
      <button onClick={() => history.push("/auth")}>Confirm</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Auth() {
  const [deleteAuth, setDeleteAuth] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setDeleteAuth(true), 3000);
  }, []);
  if (deleteAuth) return <Redirect to="/" />;
  else return <div>Auth</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/auth">
          <Auth />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have a few comments/questions. In my app, the user isn't logged in until they have confirmed their account. Basically, I just have to display the confirm page, and then when success is dispatched, it should reroute to login (no need to logout the user), but wait 3 seconds before doing so. How can I call a function like the Auth function you wrote, but without having to press a button to confirm, because by visiting the link, they automatically have confirmed. Again, I really appreciate it, it means a lot to me!

Comment: In the sandbox append /auth to URL in the nested browser (not the main browser). You’ll get the idea

Comment: Oh sweet ok that makes more sense. Do you know how I can use something similar to useEffect and useHistory for a class based component in this case?

Comment: Check the sandbox. I've added a class based component

Comment: It works!!!!! Thank you so much for helping me. I really, truly appreciate it. I've been stuck on this issue for quite some time now, and am so close to finishing this project. I'm very grateful for your taking the time to help, it really means a lot to me. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. One last thing - use the Link and. Redirect components most of the time and history.push very occasionally. If you read the react router docs it explains why but the tldr: it is simpler and more declarative. Good luck with your project!